# Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies

Tags: docker, .net-core

I tried to run console application `Net core` with Docker but got this error when start the container.

> Exception: Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its
>   dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider
>   setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libkernel32.dll: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2
WORKDIR /app 
COPY . /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Application.dll"]
```

Anyone face this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check if [`dotnet/dotnet-docker` issue 618](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/618), which does report a similar error message could help.

> Make sure you install it in your runtime and not in your dotnet build.
>
> Moving the install up to under
> `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base` solved my issue

Comment: what about macbook

Comment: @Sras Not sure, considering the OP is about a a Microsoft image, which does require a Windows kernel to run. So this should not involve MacOS.

Comment: i try running rdlc on Mac , it is working okay on windows but not mac

Comment: @Sras Then it is best to ask a separate question, with more details on your setup (including the version of the OS and of Docker)

Comment: I also got here looking for Mac help.  The question's title is generic.